# Rmarkdown renders index.html in parent directory instead of rendering the opened document

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I have a directory containing slides in a bookdown directory as follows.

```
docs
slides/01_slide.Rmd
slides/_output.yml
01_chapter.Rmd
_bookdown.yml
_output.yml
index.Rmd
...
```

I would like to build the `slides/01_slide.Rmd` using `slides/_output.yml`. When I open the `slides/01_slide.Rmd` in RStudio and hit the Knit button, the `index.Rmd` is rendered instead and the file that I have actually open is not used at all.

```
==> rmarkdown::render_site('…/slides/01_slide.Rmd',  encoding = 'UTF-8');


processing file: bookdown.Rmd
  |......................................................................| 100%
   inline R code fragments


…
output file: bookdown.knit.md


Output created: docs/index.html

Output created: …/docs/index.html
```

When I rename `index.Rmd` to something else, then `slides/01_slide.Rmd` is rendered correctly.

Is there any way to force the Knit button to render the actually opened document instead of looking for input from parent directory?

I know that I can add `knit: rmarkdown::render` in YAML and write parameters for each slide document separately but that is even more cumbersome than constantly renaming `index.html`.

(The reason that I keep slides in a bookdown directory is that I want to host the entire project in a Github repository while serving the bookdown output from `/docs`.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by adding only `knit: rmarkdown::render` in YAML. Then the Knit button triggers `render` instead of `render_site`. No additional parameters are necessary to the function and also the  `slides/_output.yml` is applied.